# Using variable from cursor for loop in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, cursor

I was doing some SQL on Oracle and I found something weird.
I have that `FOR` loop that iterate over a list of date (Stored as VARCHAR2):

```
FOR current_date in (SELECT DISTINCT DATCRE as datcre
                     FROM EVE cdv
                     WHERE cdv.datcre BETWEEN p_datedeb AND p_datefin)
LOOP
    [queries]
END LOOP;
```

I need to use `current_date` in the where clause of the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(cdv.numeve)
INTO nb
FROM EVE cdv
WHERE cdv.datcre = current_date.datcre;
```

This query doesn't work, and I get a `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.
Now, if I declare a `curDate VARCHAR2(10)` variable, store `current_date.datcre` in it and use it in the query, it works fine:

```
curDate := (current_date.datcre);

SELECT COUNT(cdv.numeve)
INTO nb
FROM EVE cdv
WHERE cdv.datcre = curDate;
```

Am I missing something or is this just the way Oracle works ?

Comment: I don't see any problem except that you are comparing two strings and not actual dates.

Comment: Since current_date is a built-in function http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions036.htm it seems like a poor choice for an implicit record.  Not certain that is causing the problem but it seems likely to cause a problem at some point.

Comment: LalitKumarB, Well the database wasn't created by me and date are always stored as strings. Since i'm processing a lot of records I think it would be worse if I used TO_DATE().
JustinCave, I'll try with a different name and update.

Comment: @JustinCave, turns out you were right, since it is a build in function when running the query Oracle takes `current_date` as the built-in function and not as the `FOR` variable, therefore current_date.[Something] doesn't make sense. Changed the name, and now everything is working fine. Thanks.